# Select2 3.4.5 force optgroup to be readonly

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

As you can see here, the I can hover on the optgroup and I can also click on it
Is there any way to make it readonly ?

The way I am loading it is:

```
formSelectElement.select2({
    placeholder: 'Type to search for a user...',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    query: getCompanyUsers,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: formSelectElement.data('primary'),
    initSelection: setAssigneeInitSelection
});
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I've added:

```
.on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    if (e.val == 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        return;
    }
});
```

I dont know if this is the best option (since this should be a default behaviour - users should not be able to click on groups) but it does the job

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary since `optGroup` is not selectable by default.

Comment: it is in my case, as you can see on the image. I can click on it and it gets selected